# pyTelegramBotAPI - how to send the messages

Tags: python, telegram

I know how to reply to commands and messages with pyTelegramBotAPI
But maybe do you know how to make it send the messages to my chat id without interaction? It doesn't execute lines of code below bot.polling()

```
import telebot
bot=telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def send_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'text')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

I want it to send the messages with a trigger on server side, not when I send a command to the bot.

Comment: You can create a funtion that send messages based on the input you give to the bot with a command, like /send hello world.

Comment: Put the line above `bot.polling()`. Please [edit] your question to add some code. [ask] and [mre] could be helpfull.

Comment: Well, sending messages based on the input - is exactly what I do not want it to do. And it doesn't send the messages before bot.polling() executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following line in your code:

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
```

Creates a `message_handler`, that can be used to **reply** on a message.

---

Since you just want to send a regular message, without any reply logic, you can use use the `bot.send_message` method, without any handlers.

Example:

```py
import telebot

# Create bot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token='ABCDEFHHIJ:AAG2snRwz8jnFtVf8b0eyCueGJRD3hY9AaQ')

# Send message
bot.send_message(123456798, 'Hi! I\'m a Bot!')
```

If I run this script, my Bot will send me the message, and terminates the script afterwards. Of course you could add the `bot.polling` at the bottom to let the Bot poll for replies or something similar.

Visual result after running the script:

[image]

Comment: We need the chat ID in the `send_message()` function, how is this working?

Comment: @Logixor the chat ID is a constant value that should be determined beforehand

Comment: @TheEyesHaveIt I figured it out eventually, thanks for the input anyways.